# Is there in Qt forms onChange event?

Tags: c++, qt, delphi, events

Is there in Qt something like `Form.onChange` in Delphi?

I found some `changeEvent` method but when I wrote connect 
`connect(this, SIGNAL(this->changeEvent),this, SLOT(checkIfSomethingChanged()));`

and tried to check it like that

```
void importdb_module::checkIfSomethingChanged(){

    QMessageBox::information(0, "", "Test");
}
```

I realized that it not works.

I want to check some condition everytime when something changed in my form, how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The changeEvent slot is a virtual, protected function found in QWidget. Therefore, if you inherit from QWidget or any QWidget derived class, you'll be able to override that function. For example: -

```
class MyForm : public QWidget
{
    protected slots:
        virtual void changeEvent(QEvent * event);
}


void MyForm::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    // Do something with the event    
}
```

If you wanted to know outside of the event that the form has been changed, you can add a signal to the form and emit it from the changeEvent to pass the event on: -

```
class MyForm : public QWidget
{
   signals:
        void FormChanged(QEvent* event);

    protected slots:
        virtual void changeEvent(QEvent * event);
}


void MyForm::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    emit FormChanged(event);
}
```

Now connect another class to the new signal, using Qt 5 connect syntax: -

```
connect(myFormObject, &MyForm::FormChanged, someclassObject, &SomeClass::HandleFormChanged);
```

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work, because you mixed up two concepts: events and signal/slots. To make it work, you need to override your class' `changeEvent()` virtual function. Something like this:

```
void MyWidget::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "", "Test");
}
```

Comment: oh, that worked! but there are new problem - messagebox appears every second!

Comment: @DanilGholtsman, that is expected, because your object is changing every second:) Try to get rid of message box and write into debug output with `qDebug() << "I am changed";`.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, mister! if I'd be able to accept more than one answers I accepted your answer too, sorry for that